# During publish create empty directory inside wwwroot even if the directory is empty

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have `wwwroot/print/data/` empty folder in my blazor server project. But when I publish the project. The `wwwroot` folder does not contain `print/data/` subfolder. But It is created if `print/data/` folder has some file inside it. I want the publish project to have `print/data/` even if the folder is empty.

**Clearification:** By published project I mean in solution explorer window when you right-click on the project and then click publish. The project in the publish directory is created.

**Software Information:**

- .NET version: 5.0
- Project: Blazor Server Side

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<Target Name="CreateFolder" AfterTargets="Publish">` in your .csproj file. It works for me.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CreateFolder" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishDir)wwwroot\print\data" Condition="!Exists('$(PublishDir)wwwroot\print\data')" />
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(PublishDir)wwwroot\print\data\.log" Lines="Generated file for publish" Overwrite="True" Condition="!Exists('$(PublishDir)wwwroot\print\data\.log')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

---

**After test and read a lot blogs, we can find if the folder is empty, it will ignore during publish process.**

Maybe we can create a sample file under the `data` folder, I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: Ya, I also think the sample data is easier. But it seems like a hack rather than a solution. I mean I can also just create the folder inside the published project. I was hoping that was a way to change the configuration so that it does not ignore the empty folders.

Comment: @KevinStephenBiswas This is the default behavior at compile time. The .csproj is here to allow these special operations, how is it a hack ?

Comment: @KevinStephenBiswas https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/makedir-task?view=vs-2022    Official doc mentioned this usage .